# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'chromedriver'

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, permissions, selenium-chromedriver

Hi guys i am trying to setup chromedriver,but i am getting the following error

chrome version : 84.0.4147.105 and correspond driver dwonloaded from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

also followed the steps given [here](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/)

But when i try to run my scripts it is giving me an error :

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'chromedriver'
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Also,

> whereis chromedriver

```
chromedriver: /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

> chromedriver -v

Command 'chromedriver' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver

Comment: are you using macbook ?

Comment: No Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Python 3.8 @JustinLambert

Comment: you need to allow developer options in security and privacy section in your machine(Computer)

Comment: @JustinLambert can you please help me wth the stpes or any link?

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4616

https://github.com/Paperspace/DinoRunTutorial/issues/7

Comment: @JustinLambert i already tried the steps mentioned there, but still not working

Comment: what is your chrome  browser version ?

Comment: @JustinLambert chrome version : 84.0.4147.105

Comment: chrome driver exe version ?

Comment: @JustinLambert unable to find that, when i am trying to find version, its throws an error as, "Command 'chromedriver' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver" also, have downloaded https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/ from [https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly press (ctrl + alt + T) open your Terminal.
And run this command apt-get update
Or update the Chromium Browser.

Comment: i am using chrome browser, not chromium.version is 84